# Neo4j transaction logs not pruned despites aggressiv retention_policy

Tags: neo4j, transactions

i am filling a new Neo4j 4.0.9 enterprise database. As the inital dataloading blows up the transactions logs and i am running out of disk space, i am trying to prune transaction logs aggresiv.

```
.conf$ cat neo4j.config
...
dbms.tx_log.rotation.size=100M
dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=10 files
dbms.checkpoint.interval.tx=500
dbms.checkpoint.interval.time=120s
...
```

But it seems neo4j ignores all my settings.

The Transaction directory is always blowing up fast.

```
.data/$ du -h --max-depth 1
8.0K    ./dbms
9.9G    ./transactions
1.7G    ./databases
```

And iam not understanding why there are so many files despite `dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=10 files`

```
.data/transactions/neo4j$ ls
neostore.transaction.db.0    neostore.transaction.db.34  neostore.transaction.db.67
neostore.transaction.db.1    neostore.transaction.db.35  neostore.transaction.db.68
neostore.transaction.db.10   neostore.transaction.db.36  neostore.transaction.db.69
neostore.transaction.db.100  neostore.transaction.db.37  neostore.transaction.db.7
neostore.transaction.db.101  neostore.transaction.db.38  neostore.transaction.db.70
neostore.transaction.db.102  neostore.transaction.db.39  neostore.transaction.db.71
neostore.transaction.db.103  neostore.transaction.db.4   neostore.transaction.db.72
neostore.transaction.db.104  neostore.transaction.db.40 ...
```

Also tried `false`, `1G size` for `dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy`

The settings arriving in the DB. Checked via

```
CALL dbms.listConfig("dbms.checkpoint.interval")
YIELD name, value
RETURN name, value
UNION
CALL dbms.listConfig("dbms.tx_log")
YIELD name, value
RETURN name, value
```

with the result

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════╤══════════╕
│"name"                                 │"value"   │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════╪══════════╡
│"dbms.checkpoint.interval.time"        │"2m"      │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│"dbms.checkpoint.interval.tx"          │"500"     │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│"dbms.tx_log.preallocate"              │"true"    │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│"dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy"│"10 files"│
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│"dbms.tx_log.rotation.size"            │"100MiB"  │
└───────────────────────────────────────┴──────────┘
```

i cant find my mistake... any ideas?

Comment: Could you find a solution? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by uncommenting and setting the following setting in neo4j.conf:

```
dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=keep_none
```

The conf file is specific for the DB and is located as follows (on OSX):

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/com.Neo4j.Relate/Data/dbmss/dbms-7cea3976-b1eb-43fb-a1a0-252dec57d656/conf/neo4j.conf
```

It is not a best practice because it makes incremental backup impossible, but for initial data loading and processing it is the way to go.

You'll need to restart your DB to clear the log files already there.

It worked for me for Neo4j 4.1.3